# Is there evidence to suggest the girl at the Bajoran ophanage in "Cardassians" is Gul Dukat's daughter?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In the *DS9* episode ["Cardassians"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardassians_(Star_Trek:_Deep_Space_Nine)), we see a visit to a Bajoran orphanage. At the end of the visit, a Cardassian orphan girl rushes out to wave goodbye to the visitors, [and says](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/425.txt):

> Excuse me, sir. Have you come to take us back to Cardassia?

Later, in Season 4, Episode 5 ["Indiscretion"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Indiscretion_(episode)), we meet Gul Dukat's daughter [Ziyal](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tora_Ziyal) who is a "prisoner of war" on Bajor.

**Is there evidence to suggest the girl at the Bajoran ophanage in "Cardassians" is Gul Dukat's daughter?**

Comment: Good heavens—even _Star Trek_ has been invaded by the Kardashians? How horrid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## There is no evidence

The exchange in the episode is between the girl (Asha) and Garak.  From the script you linked to:

```
      The Cardassian girl, Asha, and the Cardassian boy tentatively 
step forward to Garak...

                ASHA
        Excuse me, sir... have you come to 
        take us back to Cardassia?

                GARAK
        I'm afraid not, child.
```

Dukat was not present, and so we do not see his reaction to the girl.

The *DS9 Companion* makes no reference to Asha being a possible child of Dukat, and no interviews with Ira Steven Behr or other *DS9* staff mention a possible connection.

Marc Alaimo (Dukat) has commented on the episode, but only to discuss his portrayal of Dukat as a man torn between what he wants to do and what he is ordered to do — he said nothing about Asha.

## Other points to consider

Since part of reason you are drawing a parallel with Ziyal is your assumption that Ziyal was a prisoner of war on Bajor, note they Ziyal was *never* a prisoner on Bajor.  She and her mother were on a transport bound for Lissepia, allies of the Cardassians who agreed to take in children born from Cardassian fathers and Bajoran mothers to spare men like Dukat from scandal on Cardassia Prime, as revealed in ["Indiscretions"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Indiscretion_(episode)).  However, they were intercepted by the Breen and captured, and subsequently forced to work in a Breen labour camp.  Kira and Dukat liberated Ziyal from the Breen in the episode.

Finally, unlike Ziyal, who was half Bajoran, Asha appears fully Cardassian.  It is unlikely that Dukat had relations with Cardassian women on Bajor, given his persistent preference for Bajoran women when Bajoran women are available....